# typeof this in virtual methods called from derived class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, virtual-functions

I have found myself in a situation where I have a method on a base class which makes a call to a generic method passing itself as a parameter (via `this`). In the generic method the type is always the base type, even when I call the method from a derived class.

I need the generic method to know that it is of the derived type and not the base type.

I am not able to change the generic method since it is from a third party app (http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ - `Razor.Parse` method).

I have found that if I define the method as a generic extension method restricted to types inheriting from my base class that calling this then works but it seems messy to use extension methods for this purpose (though if this is correct usage I'd be happy to hear that). What I am wondering if there is some trick I can use that will convert "this" to the type of the derived object before it gets called (maybe using generics still).

I have included a simplified program below that should be self contained (I'm running it in LINQPad for personal ease). Essentially I want a method defined on `A` that when called on an instance of `B` will call `Test.WhatType` and output "B".

I hope this makes sense.

```
void Main()
{
    var bar = new B();
    bar.myGetType();
    bar.ExtGetType();
}

class A
{
    public virtual void myGetType()
    {
        Test.WhatType(this);
        this.ExtGetType();
    }
}

class B : A {}

static class ext
{
    public static void ExtGetType<T>(this T obj) where T : A
    {
        Test.WhatType(obj);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void WhatType<T>(T obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Changed method name to `A.myGetType()` since I hadn't even noticed I was overloading accidentally.

N.B. Running this code outputs:

```
A
A
B
```

Comment: If your generic method cares about the type, past `where T : A`, then you need to reevaluate that method.

Comment: Well, it's kinda right - the calling code IS class A! (I know that's not helpful) I'll have a dig and try get back to you!

Comment: You will have to use obj.GetType() instead in the WhatType method.

Comment: Also, GetType is a method on object that is not marked virtual.  Please do not try to override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that `A.GetType()` is binding to `WhatType<A>` as that is all it knows about.

So you have to let class `A` know about the derived classes.

You can do this with self-referencing generic types. Something like:

```
class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    public virtual void GetType()
    {
        Test.WhatType<T>( (T) this );
    }
}

class B : A<B> { }
```

then:

```
new B().GetType();
```

will bind to `WhatType<B>` and so will output `B`

Comment: Ah, this was the kind of thing I was wondering about. I'm not sure now I see it as a solution whether that is any neater but thank you for sharing. This certainly looks like it will be useful in general. :)

Comment: The call to the extension method from inside `A.GetType()` outputs `A` - I thought you wanted it to output `B`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your followup question.

Comment: ok :) `Main` calls `bar.myGetType()` which in turn calls `this.ExtGetType()` which the compiler resolves to `ExtGetType<A>` and so outputs `A` - the second `A` in your sample output. I thought you wanted it to output `B`?

Comment: I've changed the correct answer to this one now since although the other one helped me more it didn't answer the question directly which was how to make the static method output B. This answer did so is in fact the correct one. :)

Comment: That is correct and your code does indeed fix this issue (and in fact I just switched the correct answer as a result of this). I think I'm confused by why you are double checking this and wonder if it was because of which answer I marked correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `obj.GetType()`. `T` is bound at compile-time, not a run time and thus `typeof(T)` returns the compile-time type of `T`.

Comment: Ah. Yes, so my testing was wrong it looks like. `Test.WhatType` was meant to be a simulation of the static method in the third party app that seems to be considering the passed paramter as the base class instead. It looks like my issue might actually be with the RazorEngine library then. I'll go look there. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: And indeed I have now found that the `Razor.Parse` method I was calling does indeed appear to use `typeof(T)` internally rather than `mode.GetType()`. I guess I'll go complain at them. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This method returns the type of the static type (T). It should be implemented as

```
public static void WhatType<T>(T obj) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().Name); 
}
```

Edit:
I just realized what you want is to manipulate A in such a way that the T of the generic method changes. You can either do this via reflection or by adding a switch statement based on the subtype of A and explicitly cast this to B (or whatever class). Of course none of this solutions is good because A would take dependency on its subclasses and reflection plainly sux. Another option is to override the GetType() method in each subclass and thus move the responsibility to the subclasses.

Comment: typeof requires a Type.  I think you mean obj.GetType()

Comment: This will never compile. `obj` is not a valid parameter to `typeof`. It expects a type name.

Comment: A note, not a criticism of your answer: that'll only work because you/the OP haven't put the `where T : A` in. If you add that, then `A.GetType()` will be used instead of `Object.GetType()`. (`A.GetType` is very poorly named.)

Comment: Yeah and in fact it will generate a warning because A.GetType hides Object.GetType (and there is no "new" keyword).

Comment: @hvd: that was just some very poor naming on my part. `A.GetType` has been changedto `A.myGetType` now to differentiate it. Thanks for the observation.